# Curl PHP нет реакции на CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER и CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST

Tags: php, curl

Скрипт не реагирует на:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

В некоторых случаях, скрипт отлично справляется и с https://, в некоторых нет (50 на 50). В результате получаю ответ:

bool(false)

Warning: curl_getinfo(): 4 is not a valid cURL handle resource in /home/ru/cgi/runphp.php(95) : eval()'d code on line 63

Warning: curl_errno(): 4 is not a valid cURL handle resource in /home/ru/cgi/runphp.php(95) : eval()'d code on line 64

Доступа к файлу php.ini нет, для возможности добавления сертификата в доверенные. . .

Версия php - 5.2.12

Версия Curl - libcurl/7.21.0 GnuTLS/2.8.6 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.15

OpenSSL - OpenSSL 1.0.2p 14 Aug 2018

Помогите, чем кто может!!! Благодарю заранее.

Образец скрипта:

```
$urlrest = "https://instant-monitor.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($сh, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlrest);
$abc = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'curl_getinfo - '. curl_getinfo($ch) .'<br/><br/>';
echo 'curl_errno - '. curl_errno($ch) .'<br/><br/>';
echo 'curl_error - '. curl_errno($ch) .'<br/><br/>';
curl_close($ch);
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($abc);
var_dump($abc);
```

Comment: Вы вызываете curl_errno и curl_getinfo после закрытия $ch через curl_close, поэтому и предупреждения. Делайте это ДО вызова функции закрытия чтобы получить описание ошибки, которая, надеюсь, укажет вам на проблемы с адресами, к которым вы делаете вызовы. А уже после этого сможете понять, проблема ли это с сертификатом, либо с чем-то еще.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, уже хоть какой-то сдвиг есть. Сделал как вы сказали и получил следующую информацию: 

curl_getinfo - Array

curl_errno - 28

Comment: А где URL, по которому идёт запрос? Где его тип, параметры и т.д? Мы не сможем вам помочь если не будет [минимально-достаточного и воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Прошу прощения, подправил скрипт, внес URL в строку $ch = curl_init();

Comment: с ошибкой 28 разобрался. Это реакция скрипта на CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, перевел его в 0, чтоб убрать ограничения по времени загрузки. При этом возникает следующая проблема, скрипт больше не выводит никаких ошибок и желаемого результата так же нет, пустой экран.

Comment: Видимо у вас какие-то блокировки, попробуйте запустить трассировку и выяснить через какие направления идёт запрос.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как выполнить трассировку?

Comment: Нет никого кто бы смог справился с данной задачей?